# Is there any repellent against wasps, bees and hornets?

Tags: bugs, bees, wasps

On my trip I've been accompanied by a few wasps. I don't know what attracted them but they were trying to sit on me, which wasn't comfortable to me, since a bite of a wasp is causing by me a swelling of a few cm size...

So, I'm wondering, if there's any repellent against wasps and other Hymenoptera (bees, hornets etc.) that can be used outdoor and is not interferring with repellents against mosquitoes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My mother swears by a combination wasp-repellant and sunscreen that she buys from Boots in England. I see they also carry wasp repellant alone, at http://www.boots.com/en/Boots-Pharmaceuticals-Repel-Insect-Repellent-Spray-Wasp-120ml-_1207452/#detailedInfo

[image: wasp repellant]

You could poke around a little on sites like that, or just go to a largish pharmacy and see what you can find.

Comment: Any idea why the linked page says: "Do not use under clothing." ?